# How to prevent reload and show custom popup?

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks

I have a form, when my user tries to reload, I need to show the popup `"If you reload the page you cannot use this form"`.

the page is reloaded using a button in browsers [image]

How to prevent reload and show custom popup ?

Comment: there is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event, but i don't think you can prvent reload, you are not a browser owner to forbid user close/reload page. You better to save form data and restore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browsers are designed to ask for confirmation with the native popup https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event

And this cannot be customized (which would require async handling)

If the latter was possible people would get stuck on porn pages and would never have the chance to leave them.

Comment: lol imagine the tabs during screen sharing